# How to use the node title in the "Override title" field of contextual filter

Tags: 8, views

Situation:

- A view has a contextual filter on a field named `type`.
- The view sorts by date and has the pager set to display 1 item (I want only the newest node).
- I want to show `type` + the node title as the view title.
- So, what I want to put in the **Override title** field is

  {{ arguments.field_type_value }} {{ title }}

But `{{ title }}` doesn't work. It outputs nothing. This isn't a surprise because (a) `{{ title }}` isn't in the Replacement Patterns list and (b) I assume the view expects to display multiple nodes, so there isn't just one `{{ title }}` to display.

Is there a straightforward way to do what I want to do using a view as I'm doing? There are reasons why I want to use a view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add title as a field and checkmark hide from display, now `{{ title }}` should work despite not being listed as replacement pattern.

Also make sure your view's title is set to none

[image]

---

Alternatively, you could also solve it by not overriding it in the contextual filter settings and instead overwrite it directly in the view's title.

Add title and type as fields, hide them if you want/need to.

[image]

---

But, if you're using teaser

[image]

The above two solutions won't work, so you can solve it programmatically:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_post_render()
 */
function mymodule_views_post_render($view) {
  if ($view->id() == "view_name" && $view->current_display == 'page_1') {
    $node = $view->result[0]->_entity;
    $new_title = $node->type->entity->label() . ' ' . $node->getTitle();
    $view->setTitle($new_title);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @No Sssweat. I'm using Show: Content, so I updated my question to reflect that. Your coded solution worked perfectly for me. I also tested your first two solutions with Show: Fields and they work in that case as well. I've never used views_post_render before. And I had no idea Twig syntax can be used in a title field, so I learned something new there as well!